# How to avoid rebuilding the graph in Tensorflow when doing hyper-parameter optimization

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a Tensorflow model that I am optimizing using Optunity.

The way I am doing things is that I have an objective function that creates a model and returns the best loss of my model. I pass this function to optunity which runs different tests with different parameters each time i.e it builds the graph each time.

In my code, I am using `tf.reset_default_graph()` before creating an instance of my model. Hence, it is rebuilding the model every time.

My issue is that having to build the graph every time I am using a new combination of hyper-parameters takes a lot of time. Is there a way to make things faster?

If I do not use `tf.reset_default_graph()` I get errors about conflicting tensors.

Comment: You can always save the model to file and then load it back in. Not sure if that's what you are after? Building the graph shouldn't take too long in my experience though. Defining the layers takes a couple of seconds for me but perhaps if you're applying weights every time then it's quite cumbersome. Try looking at: http://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/